# Need help with simple rewrite rule (should't this be easy?)

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, mapping, buddypress

All I need is a rewrite that will change "domainXYZ.com/anyphrase" into "domainXYZ.com"

Here is what I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainXYZ\.com
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !wp-admin
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !activity
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !members
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !groups
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php [L]
```

Notes: I added the above to the top of my .htaccess (in WP root). I am running WP 3.1.3 multisite (subdomains), WP MU Domain Mapping plugin, and buddypress on domainXYZ.com. domainXYZ.com is the mapped domain name, not the actual subdomain.

I was assuming that my rewrite rule would load domainXYZ.com/index.php, which would load the homepage for the wordpress site. However, I get a "page not found" response shown in my buddypress skin (not a full-blown error 404 page).

Thanks to anyone who can help, Joe

Comment: If my solution doesn't work for you, you can add RewriteLogLevel 1000, and RewriteLog /tmp/rewritelog to the main httpd.conf. That will log apache's rewrite path as it tries to rewrite the url. It will create a LOT of output, but it should help figuring out the problem.

Comment: I'm working off a shared server for this particular project, but I just emailed support to ask how I might access Rewrite Logging. If I hear back, and am able to learn anything from the logs, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the rules in an .htaccess, i believe that you need to use RewriteBase.

This should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

In the main httpd.conf file, inside the directory block for the document root, at the bottom, you can add this (instead of the .htaccess):

```
<Directory /my/document/root>
    # Other stuff here
    # ...

    # make this last:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! RewriteBase seemed like a promising solution, but my rewrite rule is still sending me to the "page not found" response page in my theme.

I'm not sure how familiar you are with Buddypress, but do you think maybe the bp-core-catchuri.php file is causing some confliction?

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would let people know that I went a different route with this challenge. Instead of trying to get my rewrite to work, I just changed the way WP dealt with a 404.

Unfortunately, I had to alter some WP core files, but the functions I changed were:

`set_404();` (this allowed me to communicate to my theme that certain 404's should instead load the home template)

and

`status_header();` (to stop from sending the 404 header when a specific type of nonexistent url is entered)